# Trouble starting sinatra application

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

I have cloned a sinatra application and am trying to run the application. I have followed the steps in the in the repo read me but when I run:

> rackup -p 4567

the server starts but I get the following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad at /
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Any help is appriciated, Thanks

Comment: can you connect to Postgres manually?

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed? Have you setup the database for this app? If you run macOS you can install Postgres with `brew install postgresql`. You would have to refer to the documentation of the app you cloned for info on actually setting up the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PostgreSQL is not running or not accepting connections at `127.0.0.1:5432`

Meaning you should start a PostgreSQL server and if it's already running check your firewall configuration. (Or if your PostgreSQL server is running at `127.0.0.1:4000` for example, you need to adjust your application config to these values)

Comment: Thank you, The firewall was causing part of the problem and blocking my connection. I also realized that  PostgreSQL version 11 is not compatible with windows 10 so I downgraded to version 10.